# How to send commands to a USB device on OS X without dependencies (only from command line)?

Tags: macos, command-line, usb

I'm writing a script and want it to be portable as possible (as in, the end user doesn't have to download any other dependencies), however I *can* assume it'll only run on OS X.

To that end, I want to recreate [some Python](https://gist.github.com/nicholaspearson/8e9c89bbf66f8bca9327) that changes a [Luxafor flag](https://luxafor.com/) status.

I can detect the USB is plugged in with:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep LUXAFOR
```

However I got stuck on how to proceed. The [Python script](https://github.com/iamthefox/luxafor/blob/master/src/Device.js) shows what data I need to send, but I can't figure out how to do it straight from the command line.

I have tried to look in `/dev/tty*` but I can't see any folder mounted or unmounted when I plug it in the Luxafor or not (I did a diff between `ls -1 /dev/tty*` before and after).

Which commands do I have to use for this to work?

Comment: Does your device implement any specific USB device classes, like Human Interface Device (HID)?  Do you have have any way of figuring out what the right USB commands are to send?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Hi David, I got it to work using `hidapitester`. A command such as `hidapitester --vidpid 04d8/f372 --open --length 4 --send-output 1,FF,FF,0,0` worked to change the color.